# Flask restful can't map to pathparam Resource

Tags: python, rest, api, flask, flask-restful

I have a flask restful resource like this:

```
api.add_resource(TrainerById, '/api/trainer/<int:uuid>')
```

with the source code like this:

```
class TrainerById(Resource):
    def get(self):
        data = trainer_by_id_parser.parse_args()
        trainer_uuid = data['uuid']
        new_trainer = Trainer.find_by_uuid(trainer_uuid)
        if not new_trainer:
            return {'msg': f"Trainer with uuid {trainer_uuid} not found"}, 401
        else:
            return {'msg': to_json_trainer(new_trainer)}
```

I want to return the `trainer` profile of the trainer with the UUID from the path param, however the issue is that, it returns a 404 whenever I try to access the endpoint like such:

```
localhost:5000/api/trainer/profile/886313e1-3b8a-5372-9b90-0c9aee199e5d #gives 404
```

Comment: well check parts of your connection string which aren't dynamic. For example check if your prefix is really `localhost:5000`

Comment: `profile` is missing from your add_resource argument, as such it is `/api/trainer/<int:uuid>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mixed resourceful routing with argument parsing.

`Resourceful Routing` are endpoints of an app.

Listed below are the examples of different routes:

- `localhost:5000/api/trainer/`
- `localhost:5000/api/trainer/profile`
- `localhost:5000/api/trainer/profile/6385d786-ff51-455e-a23f-0699c2c9c26e`
- `localhost:5000/api/trainer/profile/4385d786-ef51-455e-a23f-0c99c2c9c26d`

Note that last two can be grouped by using *resourceful routing*.

`RequestParser` is Flask-RESTPlus built-in support for request data validation. Those can be querystring or POST form encoded data etc.

---

With incomplete code you gave, the functionality you want can be implemented like so:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restplus import Resource, Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

# List of trainers, just basic example instead of DB.
trainers = [
    '6385d786-ff51-455e-a23f-0699c2c9c26e',
    '7c6d64ae-8334-485f-b402-1bf08aee2608',
    'c2a427d5-5294-4fad-bf10-c61018ba49e1'
]


class TrainerById(Resource):

    def get(self, trainer_uuid):

        # In here, trainer_uuid becomes <class 'uuid.UUID'>, so you can
        # convert it to string.

        if str(trainer_uuid) in trainers:
            return {'msg': f"Trainer with UUID {trainer_uuid} exists"}, 200
        else:
            return {'msg': f"Trainer with uuid {trainer_uuid} not found"}, 404

# This means after profile/, next expected keyword is UUID with name in route
# as trainer_uuid.
api.add_resource(TrainerById, '/api/trainer/profile/<uuid:trainer_uuid>')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Insite the get function in TrainerById, it receives 'self', can I get from there the route associated with it? Suppose inside the 'get' function I want to print: '/api/trainer/profile/<uuid:trainer_uuid> with GET method'. How can I do that?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achive. If someone sends `GET` request on `/api/trainer/profile/<uuid:trainer_uuid>`, you can basically print. For example `print(Received GET request on /api/trainer/profile/{}.format(trainer_uuid))`. But logging is enabled by default.